# Akamai charge questions

Tags: akamai

I am wondering if anyone has an simple answer to this.  If you hit an Akamai server for an image, but the response is returned with a 304 code instead of a 200, does Akamai charge for the call since no data is returned with a 304 and image is served from the browser cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by charge you mean count against your monthly bandwidth allotment, then no. Assuming you're using their Origin Pull service, the only exception is if the file is in your cache but not stored on Akamai's edge servers. In that case, Akamai pulls the file from your server which would incur a small bandwidth hit as both incoming and outgoing traffic is counted on Akamai.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how you are being billed.  By bandwidth or by pageviews?

If by bandwidth, then yes, you would be charged and bits would be delivered on your behalf.

There is no discrepancy if your object is in cache.  If the object is in cache, then Akamai won't need to go back to origin to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

3xx responses still transfer a small number of bytes per request to tell you about the response. This typically consists of HTTP headers / cookies + 3xx response and the URL it wants to redirect you to.

Therefore you will be incurring a small amount of cost between your user and the edge node, and if the request is a cache miss or not cacheable, then also bandwidth cost between your origin server and Akamai.